# SCP Command in Solaris to file transfer from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, solaris, file-transfer, scp

Is There any way to do following in `C#.NET` or `JAVA`,

Get list of files from specific directory of Another pc having `solaris` OS and transfer file using `SCP` to another pc which have also `solaris` OS.

Actually i am thinking about creating front-end in asp.net to transfer backup from Live to backup server and get information about backup.

I even this is possible or not, but I wan't to clear my confusion on this.

Please give me your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

C# or any other .NET language is specific for Windows and won't run on anything but Windows. So forget about .NET languages. For this type of task I would definitely use Java if you insist on using a programming language at that level.

From Java you can use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library. It can do SCP from within Java. Here's is [one example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java).

However I must say that most people that are familiar with Unix/Linux would probably simply do this task from within a scripting environment. Heck it can be done from Bash if you like.

Regardless of your choice of tool/prg.language you'll also have to decide if your doing PUSH or PULL. It seems from your posting that you are most keen on doing a PULL. There's no right or wrong answer on PUSH vs PULL.